# Are Static functions in ES6 a substitute for Mixins that were used in React?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, mixins, static-functions

I'm new to React. Can somebody explain why ES6 is launched without any mixin support. Since, there is no support for mixins when you use React with ES6 classes. 
Can we use Static functions instead of Mixins in React to do the same thing?

Comment: You should look into using [Higher Order Components](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/higher-order-components.html). These are functions that take a component as a parameter and return a new component that can wrap functionality around the input component.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelLyons, looking into HOC helps.